# accessing the attribute of graphic?

Tags: highcharts

I am able to set the colour of a graphic using the following code:

```
chart.series[1].data[1].graphic.attr("fill","red");
```

However, if I try to retrieve the value, i get a null response: NaN

```
console.log(chart.series[1].data[1].graphic.attr("fill"));
```

How do I check the current fill?

Many thanks

Comment: You can do it using `firebug`. You can simple log `chart` and navigate thrue it's values until found what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use

```
chart.series[0].data[0].graphic.fill
```

http://jsfiddle.net/EzxJ9/1/